# How to query in pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

How can I query in my pivot table if the user already exist in the group ?

I have USERS table, GROUPS table, and GROUP_USER table. In the group user table wherein the id's of the two tables stored so I want to check in my condition if he/she already existed there will be a message.

Here is the code of my current query statement to check if it is existed:

```
Group::where('user_id', '=', $user)
     ->where('group', '=', $group->user->id)
     ->first;
```

Answer:

`if ($group) {
            if ($group->users()->where('users.id', $user)->exists()) {
                Session::flash('info', 'You\'re already part of the group', $group->group_name);
            } else {
                $group->users()->attach($user);
                Session::flash('success', 'You are now part of the group' . ' ' . $group->group_name);
            }
        } elseif ($false) {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Invalid group code');
        }
        return back();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as:

```
$group->users()->where('users.id', $user)->exists()
```

To insert in pivot table you can use `attach` method as:

```
$group->users()->attach($user_id)
```

**Update**

From the comments, your code should be as:

```
if ($group) { 
    if($group->user()->where('users.id', $user)->exists()) {
        Session::flash('info', 'Already part of this group'); 
    } else {
        $group->users()->attach($user); 
        Session::flash('success', 'You are now part of the group!'); 
    }
} else { 
    Session::flash('danger', 'Wrong Group Code!'); 
}
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: I received the same error for this syntax "Duplicate entry '2-3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `group_user` (`created_at`, `group_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (2016-12-19 23:12:05, 3, 2016-12-19 23:12:05, 2))" "

Comment: From where this insert query came in?

Comment: $user = Auth::user()->id;
        $group_code = $request['group_code'];
        $group = Group::where('group_code', '=', $group_code)->first();

        if ($group) {
            $group->users()->attach($user);
            Session::flash('success', 'You are now part of the group!');
            return redirect()->back();
        }elseif (Group::user()->where('id', $user)->exists()){
            Session::flash('info', 'Already part of this group');
        }
        else {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Wrong Group Code!');
        }

Comment: Your `Group::user()->where('id', $user)->exists()` is the problem. Use my first code for this.

Comment: I still receiving the same error. The pivot table contains two primary key (composite key) the group_id and user_id and timestamps

Comment: Same error :( I don't know how to fix this error even I'm trying my best but still not enough.

Comment: try it with this query in if `$group->user()->where('users.id', $user)->exists()`

Comment: Can you give the output of `dd($group->user()->where('users.id', $user)->first())`?

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I just need to do nested if statement to fix the error :) I already update the question with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas) method like this:

```
Group::whereHas('users', function($q) use($user) {
    $q->where('id', $user->id); // check for single user id
    $q->whereIn('id', $user_ids_arr); // or use whereIn & pass array of user ids
});
```

Or if you want a `boolean` in return you can use [`exists()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists) method like this:

```
$group = Group::find($group_id);
$user_exists = $group->users()->where('id', $user_id)->exists(); 
// return 'true' if user exits else returns 'false'
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to associate users with a group you can use `attach()` like this:

```
$group->users()->attach($user_id);
```

> See more about [Updating Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

**Updated Code** - Comments

```
$user_arr = $group->users->pluck('id')->all(); // returns an array
$valid_user = in_array($user->id, $user_arr); // true / false

if ($group) {
    if($valid_user) {
        Session::flash('info', 'Already part of this group');
    } else {
        $group->users()->attach($user->id);
    }
} else {
    Session::flash('danger', 'Wrong Group Code!');
}

return redirect()->back();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second one returns an error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `group_user` (`created_at`, `group_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (2016-12-19 23:12:05, 3, 2016-12-19 23:12:05, 2))"

Comment: I dont know why the $users = User::pluck('id'); didn't work for the first using the whereHas()

Comment: According to me you're trying to insert into the table, whereas I've given you the query which reads from DB.?

Comment: You can't apply `pluck` on eloquent as its a collection method, you're doing it wrong. Can you specify what you're trying to do with code?

Comment: Yes I trying to insert id's into the pivot table. The groups table has a field user_id which is relationship who created the group. And my pivot table contains the user id and group id who joined or already part of the group.

Comment: You should use `sync` or `attach` to insert ids into pivot table!

Comment: Yes I am using the sync to insert ids into pivot table. The updated answer returns the same error :(

Comment: Please specify the eloquent query, which you're trying to execute?

Comment: if ($group) { //Is group exist?
            $group->users()->attach($user);
            Session::flash('success', 'You are now part of the group!');
            return redirect()->back();
        }elseif ($group->users()->where('id', $user)->exists()){
            Session::flash('info', 'Already part of this group');
        }
        else {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Wrong Group Code!');
            return back();
        }

Comment: The elseif condition was my main problem. It always return duplicate entry error.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: Is `$user` is an user object or a int/string, check it first, according to my code, it should be a `user` object, thats why its showing you the error!

Comment: New error even when I am not yet join to the group it returns the message 'Already part of this group'

Comment: Whats the value you're getting for `$valid_user`?

Comment: You can use `pluck` method instead. See my updated answer!